# "yield return new WaitForSeconds" Does not wait

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Summary**:
I am creating a delayed event using WaitForSeconds so that it will change what dialogue step is currently active to allow story progression, it works in certain cases and fails to work in others. I don't know what's causing it.

**Code**:

```
float waitTime = currentStep.isSpoken ? currentStep.dialogueClip.length + 1.0f : 2.0f;

    selectedText = null;

    if(currentStep.speaker.ToString() != "Gui"){
        StartCoroutine( ProgessStep(waitTime) );
    }
}

IEnumerator ProgessStep(float waitTime) {
    if(currentStep.stepName.Equals("S1-P1-1")) {
        yield break;
    }
    else if(currentStep.stepName.Equals("S2-P1-5-8")) {
        if(levelManager.fireAlarmTested) {
            SetStep("S2-P1-5-10"); 
            yield break;
        }
        else {
            levelManager.fireAlarmTested = true;
        }
    }

    if(currentStep.nextStep.Equals("")) 
        yield break;
    
    Debug.Log($"Waiting for {waitTime}s before moving to {currentStep.nextStep}");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    Debug.Log($"Moving to {currentStep.nextStep}");
    
    if(!currentStep.canRespond) 
        SetStep(currentStep.nextStep);
}
```

**Expected Result**:
It should run through a couple of checks and then wait till the audio clip (if one exists) is completed before continuing onto the next step.

**Actual result**:
It will complete according to the expected result the first time. However, if it is called again in the next step then it ignores the WaitForSeconds and goes straight into another step. This continues for a length of 4 steps before the WaitForSeconds appears to get triggered again and it ends.

**What I've Tried**:

- Using Invoke and WaitForSecondsRealtime to test if it was only in a single instance, invoke made this worse, and realtime had no change.
- Set the waitTime variable to a default value
- Included a try/catch which never triggered the catch part of it.
- Using Mathf.Ceil or CeilToInt to shorten the waitTime value from 8 decimal places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of things, the next Coroutine was being called before the previous had fully finished. This was solved by adding "StopAllCoroutines();" to the best available area before the one causing issues was called.

**Updated Code**:

```
    selectedText = null;
    
    StopAllCoroutines();
    if(currentStep.speaker.ToString() != "Gui" && !currentStep.nextStep.IsNullOrEmpty()){
        StartCoroutine( ProgressStep() );
    } else { Debug.Log($"Next step was null, so won't call ProgressStep");}
}

public IEnumerator ProgressStep() {
    if(currentStep.stepName.Equals("S1-P1-1") /*|| progressing*/) {
        yield break;
    }
    else if(currentStep.stepName.Equals("S2-P1-5-8")) {
        if(levelManager.fireAlarmTested) {
            SetStep("S2-P1-5-10"); 
            yield break;
        }
        else {
            levelManager.fireAlarmTested = true;
        }
    }

    float waitTime = currentStep.isSpoken ? currentStep.dialogueClip.length + 1.0f : 2.0f;
    
    Debug.Log($"Waiting for {Mathf.Ceil(waitTime)}s before moving to {currentStep.nextStep}");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Mathf.Ceil(waitTime));
    Debug.Log($"Moving to {currentStep.nextStep}");
    
    if(!currentStep.canRespond) 
        SetStep(currentStep.nextStep);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "Mathf.CeilToInt" method with "WaitForSeconds" , Mathf.CeilToInt rounds up the float value to nearest integer, which is causing the unexpected behavior as you mentioned.

Instead of using Mathf.CeilToInt, you can directly pass in the waitTime value to the WaitForSeconds(waitTime).